# Scope operator and Iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, containers

Why in the declaration of an iterator with C++ is necessary the scope operator **"::"**?

```
std::vector<int>::iterator i;
```

Comment: because `iterator` is special to the type of vector. If it wasn't, how would we know what `*i` returned?

Answer (score 3):

Because `iterator` is not defined in the global scope, it's a type defined in the `std::vector<int>` class.

This also mean that you could have more classes named `iterator` in different scopes, for example `std::list<...>::iterator`, `std::set<...>::iterator`, `std::map<...>::iterator` and so on; all those are different classes, all with name `iterator` but each defined in a different class.

Comment: It also means that you can refer to the iterator for a type parameter, assuming this convention is followed. eg: `T::iterator`

Answer (score 1):

iterator is a typedef in the class std::vector<>